# Bundle JS files isn't pulling through all my files.

Tags: php, jquery, html

I can't seem to make my bundle to work properly, even though I frustratingly made it work before :@.

```
<script src="js/bundle.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have this in the head so it triggers the bundle.

however when it is put on the server it seems to pull though all the JS that I need but not deploying it properly where it is needed. Very confused. I was wondering if it is something stupid with my code that is the problem, would love a second opinion.

```
<?php
$location = 'http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/js/';
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");

$libs = array(
'homeSlider.js',
'core.js',
'jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js',
'jquery-1.7.2.min.js',
'jquery-1.9.0.min.js',
'jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js',
'lightbox.js',
'modernizr.js'
);

foreach ($libs AS $lib) {   

$js=file_get_contents($location.$lib);
echo "\n" . $js . "\n";
}
```

If anyone else has had this problem I would love to know how they fixed it.

Comment: Are all of those JS files on the same server of bundle.php?

Comment: yeah they are all under the same server in the directory js/

Comment: Then you shouldn't use an URL as base location. If they are in the same dir, just use `$location = './';`. This way you avoid a useless network call (even if local)

Comment: Ah right i see what you mean, but that isn't going to stop it from working. Thanks for the point though, always good to improve things

Comment: I actually can't understand your problem. What's the issue, exactly? What do you mean by "not deploying it properly"?

Comment: Sorry been trying to fix my problem, I'll try to explain a little better. here is the url of my site in a dev folder. http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/index.html If you look at the bundle for JS it is all there all the JS that is meant to make my slider work and my pop ups. However for some reason this isn't linking up to the slider and pop ups. Even though all my JS files are in /dev/js with the bundle.php.

Comment: Can't believe how long this took me to realize that I was missing a comma on the end of the last JS file.. Could kick myself. Thanks for your help guys